Stomp over websocket , data not receiving to the client
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {

    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws");
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

}
I used SimpMessagingTemplate to send messages with in a service file like this
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notification", pushNotification);

my client code -
const {Client} = require('@stomp/stompjs');
const WebSocket = require('ws');


Object.assign(global, {
WebSocket
});
const client = new Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8088/ws',
   onConnect: () => {
    client.subscribe('user/topic/notification', message => console.log(`Received: ${message.body}`));
},
 });
client.activate();

i can connect to my web socket but unable to get data from the subscribed endpoint
